# How to get the total number of batch iteration from pytorch dataloader?

Tags: for-loop, pytorch, dataloader

I have a question that How to get the total number of batch iteration from pytorch dataloader?

The following is a common code for training

```
for i, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
```

Then, is there any method to get the total number of iteration for the "for loop"?

In my NLP problem, the total number of iteration is different from int(n_train_samples/batch_size)...

For example, if I truncate train data only 10,000 samples and set the batch size as 1024, then 363 iteration occurs in my NLP problem.

I wonder how to get the number of total iteration in "the for-loop".

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`len(dataloader)` returns the total number of batches. It depends on the `__len__` function of your dataset, so make sure it is set correctly.

Comment: @HyunseungKim Do you have the `__len__` function in your dataset? The dataloader's len function depends on the `__len__` function of the dataset. I use it daily so I am sure that it works :)

Comment: I'm sorry that I think there is some my mistakes. Actually, I tried to modify this code(https://github.com/SamLynnEvans/Transformer) for some purpose. In the script "Batch.py", there is a class which named "MyIterater" and it returns train_iter. But, I couldn't sure that it is dataloader or not... I have to check it more.

Comment: Now I undertand what your saying " It depends on the __ len __ function of your dataset, so make sure it is set correctly". __ len__ must be written.

Answer (score 3):

There is one additional parameter when creating the dataloader. It is called `drop_last`.

If `drop_last=True` then length is `number_of_training_examples // batch_size`.
If `drop_last=False` it may be `number_of_training_examples // batch_size +1`  .

```
BS=128
ds_train = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10('/data/cifar10', download=True, train=True, transform=t_train)
dl_train = DataLoader( ds_train, batch_size=BS, drop_last=True, shuffle=True)
```

For predefined datasets you may get the number of examples like:

```
# number of examples
len(dl_train.dataset)
```

The correct number of batches inside dataloader is always:

```
# number of batches
len(dl_train)
```